# mysql server initialization error if I add 'log = "testfile_log.log" '

Tags: mysql, log-files

Guys I'm just trying to set my general log file set up like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441972/how-to-see-log-files-in-mysql.

so I added `log = "testfile_log.log"` as below to my.ini

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
...
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
log = "testfile_log.log"
```

But for some reason mysql server no longer starts. Here's the log:

```
8:46:14 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
8:46:14 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
8:46:14 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
8:46:14 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
8:46:14 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
8:46:14 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
8:46:14 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

I know its related to `log = "testfile_log.log"` bcs if I take it off, it works.

Comment: the following edition solved the problem:`general-log=1
general-log-file = "you_name_it_query.log"`